# difference between 2 dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi i have a very simple question. Why when I do something like that:

```
import pandas as pd

x1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100), columns=['Test'], index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=100))
x2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100), columns=['Test2'], index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=100))

z=x1-x2
```

whereas I was waiting for z containing the difference of x1 and x2, I get a dataframe which has 2 columns:

```
    Test    Test2
2018-01-01  NaN NaN
2018-01-02  NaN NaN
2018-01-03  NaN NaN
2018-01-04  NaN NaN
2018-01-05  NaN NaN
... ... ...
2018-04-06  NaN NaN
2018-04-07  NaN NaN
2018-04-08  NaN NaN
2018-04-09  NaN NaN
2018-04-10  NaN NaN
100 rows × 2 columns
```

Thx

Comment: when subtracting on df's, it looks to match the index and column values, and since your column values are different, it returns NaN

Answer (score 0):

Your columns don't align. Not common columns are found so pandas replaces both missing columns by NaNs.

You should use Series operations:

```
z = x1['Test']-x2['Test2']
```

Output:

```
2018-01-01    1.336094
2018-01-02    0.690228
2018-01-03    1.234907
2018-01-04   -1.536592
2018-01-05   -0.320620
                ...   
2018-04-06    2.839609
2018-04-07    0.124360
2018-04-08   -2.229654
2018-04-09   -1.721601
2018-04-10   -1.704309
Freq: D, Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

Or [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) one of the columns:

```
z = x1-x2.rename(columns={'Test2': 'Test'})
```

Output:

```
                Test
2018-01-01  1.336094
2018-01-02  0.690228
2018-01-03  1.234907
2018-01-04 -1.536592
2018-01-05 -0.320620
...              ...
2018-04-06  2.839609
2018-04-07  0.124360
2018-04-08 -2.229654
2018-04-09 -1.721601
2018-04-10 -1.704309

[100 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: and if they are series ?

Comment: @jacques if they are Series, then the operation will occur without alignment on the columns (there are no columns), but alignment on the index will still occur.